# symfony 4 sets logged in as anonymous

Tags: php, symfony, security

I'm working on a `Symfony 4` project. After trying to login, it redirects me back to the login page with an anonymous token. My setup is using the login form from `symfony docs`. After clicking login my session only has the `csrf/authenticate` attribute.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

**Security.yaml**

```
security:
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
encoders:
    App\Entity\User:
        algorithm: bcrypt

providers:
    in_memory: { memory: ~ }
    db_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_MANAGER: ROLE_USER
    ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_MANAGER

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        anonymous: ~
        provider: db_provider
        form_login:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login_check
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            default_target_path: index
            always_use_default_target_path: true

        # activate different ways to authenticate

        # http_basic: true
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate

        # form_login: true
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html

# Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
# Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN}
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
    - { path: ^/register, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }


    # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

**framework.yaml**

```
framework:
secret: '%env(APP_SECRET)%'


session:
    handler_id: ~
    save_path: '/tmp'


csrf_protection: ~
```

**login template**

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
{% if error %}
    <div> {{ dump() }}
        {{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}
        {{ error.message }}


    </div>
{% endif %}
{{ dump (request) }}
<form action="{{ path('login') }}" method="post">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}"/>

    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="_password"/>

    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}"/>

    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

**SecurityController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\User;
use App\Form\EditUserFormType;
use function ContainerNbSxonP\getSecurity_AuthorizationCheckerService;
use Couchbase\Authenticator;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;

class SecurityController extends Controller {

/**
 * @Route("/", name="index")
 */
public function index()
{
    return $this->render('index.html.twig');
}

/**
 * @Route("/login/", name="login")
 */
public function login(Request $request, AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils)
{
    $session = $request->getSession();
    print_r($_POST);

    $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

    $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();



    return $this->render('Security/login.html.twig', array(
        'last_username' => $lastUsername,
        'error' => $error,
        'request' => $session
    ));
}

/**
 * @Route("/login_check", name="login_check")
 */

public function login_check()
{
}

}
```

**User.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="email", message="Email already taken")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="username", message="Username already taken")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=191, unique=true)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
private $username;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=191, unique=true)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Email()
 */

private $email;

/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Length(max=4096)
 */
private $plainPassword;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
 */
private $password;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="array")
 */
private $roles;

public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getUsername(): ?string
{
    return $this->username;
}

public function setUsername(string $username): self
{
    $this->username = $username;

    return $this;
}

public function getEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}

public function setEmail(string $email) :self
{
    $this->email = $email;

    return $this;
}

public function getPlainPassword()
{
    return $this->plainPassword;
}

public function setPlainPassword($password)
{
    $this->plainPassword = $password;
}

public function getPassword(): ?string
{
    return $this->password;
}

public function setPassword(string $password): self
{
    $this->password = $password;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Returns the roles granted to the user.
 *
 * <code>
 * public function getRoles()
 * {
 *     return array('ROLE_USER');
 * }
 * </code>
 *
 * Alternatively, the roles might be stored on a ``roles`` property,
 * and populated in any number of different ways when the user object
 * is created.
 *
 * @return (Role|string)[] The user roles
 */
public function getRoles()
{
    $roles = $this->roles;

    // give everyone ROLE_USER!
    if (!in_array('ROLE_USER', $roles)) {
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';
    }

    return $roles;
}

public function setRoles(array $roles)
{
    $this->roles = $roles;
}

/**
 * Returns the salt that was originally used to encode the password.
 *
 * This can return null if the password was not encoded using a salt.
 *
 * @return string|null The salt
 */
public function getSalt()
{
    return null;
}

/**
 * Removes sensitive data from the user.
 *
 * This is important if, at any given point, sensitive information like
 * the plain-text password is stored on this object.
 */
public function eraseCredentials()
{
    // TODO: Implement eraseCredentials() method.
}

/**
 * String representation of object
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/serializable.serialize.php
 * @return string the string representation of the object or null
 * @since 5.1.0
 */
/** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
public function serialize()
{
    return serialize(array(
        $this->id,
        $this->username,
        $this->password,
    ));
}

/** @see \Serializable::unserialize()
 * @param $serialized
 */
public function unserialize($serialized)
{
    var_dump($serialized);
    list (
        $this->id,
        $this->username,
        $this->password,
        ) = unserialize($serialized);
}
}
```

**dev.log**

```
[2018-03-29 11:54:08] request.INFO: Matched route "login". {"route":"login","route_parameters":{"_controller":"App\\Controller\\SecurityController::login","_route":"login"},"request_uri":"http://helper/login/","method":"POST"} []
[2018-03-29 11:54:08] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token. [] []
[2018-03-29 11:54:08] request.INFO: Matched route "_wdt". {"route":"_wdt","route_parameters":{"_controller":"web_profiler.controller.profiler:toolbarAction","token":"e2a230","_route":"_wdt"},"request_uri":"http://helper/_wdt/e2a230","method":"GET"} []
[2018-03-29 11:54:11] request.INFO: Matched route "_profiler". {"route":"_profiler","route_parameters":{"_controller":"web_profiler.controller.profiler:panelAction","token":"e2a230","_route":"_profiler"},"request_uri":"http://helper/_profiler/e2a230?panel=request","method":"GET"} []
[2018-03-29 11:54:11] request.INFO: Matched route "_profiler_search_bar". {"route":"_profiler_search_bar","route_parameters":{"_controller":"web_profiler.controller.profiler:searchBarAction","_route":"_profiler_search_bar"},"request_uri":"http://helper/_profiler/search_bar?panel=request","method":"GET"} []
```

**session dump after login**

```
Session {#1549 ▼
 #storage: NativeSessionStorage {#1550 ▼
    #bags: array:2 [▼
      "attributes" => SessionBagProxy {#1623 ▼
        -bag: AttributeBag {#1608 ▼
          -name: "attributes"
          -storageKey: "_sf2_attributes"
          #attributes: &1 array:2 [▶]
         }
         -data: &2 array:2 [▶]
        -hasBeenStarted: &4 true
       }
      "flashes" => SessionBagProxy {#1624 ▼
         -bag: FlashBag {#1609 ▼
          -name: "flashes"
          -flashes: &3 []
          -storageKey: "_symfony_flashes"
        }
        -data: &2 array:2 [▼
          "_sf2_attributes" => &1 array:2 [▼
            "_csrf/authenticate" =>
"x6_X_CknVoh13DWDOWOIxGOnaxdyr_vTQbp9iQW3j-E"
            "_security.main.target_path" => "http://helper/"
          ]
          "_symfony_flashes" => &3 []
        ]
        -hasBeenStarted: &4 true
      }
    ]
    #started: true
    #closed: false
    #saveHandler: SessionHandlerProxy {#1579 ▼
      #handler: StrictSessionHandler {#1606 ▼
        -handler: SessionHandler {#1607}
        -doDestroy: null
        -sessionName: "PHPSESSID"
        -prefetchId: null
        -prefetchData: null
        -newSessionId: null
        -igbinaryEmptyData: null
      }
      #wrapper: false
      #saveHandlerName: "user"
    }
    #metadataBag: MetadataBag {#1551 ▼
      -name: "__metadata"
      -storageKey: "_sf2_meta"
      #meta: & array:3 [▼
        "u" => 1522332857
        "c" => 1522314558
        "l" => "0"
      ]
      -lastUsed: 1522332823
      -updateThreshold: 0
    }
  }
  -flashName: "flashes"
  -attributeName: "attributes"
  -data: &2 array:2 [▶]
  -hasBeenStarted: &4 true
}
```